# Programming best practices : to initialize or not to

Tags: java, initialization

Which is better ?

Case 1 :

```
set = new set<>();

if(flagEnabled) {
  set = generateSet();
}

update(set);
```

Case 2 :

```
set; // no initialization

if(flagEnabled) {
  set = generateSet();
} else {
  set = new set();
}

update(set);
```

Which one is desirable ?

Comment: I'd say don't allocate memory you're not planning on using.  You're just wasting the garbage collector's time.

Comment: How about `set = flagEnabled ? generateSet() : new set()`?

Comment: What does `generateSet()` do? Can you move the `if` statement inside of the function call and simply do `set = generateSet()`?

Comment: I tend to initialize things so that I don't have to remember to check for `null` all over the place.  It's a habit I picked up from Scala, where declaring a `var` or `val` without initializing it is a syntax error.

Comment: In your case, your initializing to something anyway. The only difference is the first may cause the first object assignment to be made available to the the gc in the near future, so it might not be the most efficient

Answer (score 5):

Pick the second case: there is a path through your code where an object is created only to be discarded and replaced with another one.

It is best to initialize your object unconditionally, though: you can do it by picking the appropriate option with a ternary operator, like this:

```
set s = flagEnabled ? generateSet() : new set();
```

The conditional logic remains in place, but now it is combined with initialization, making your intent easier to see.

Answer (score 3):

There is no logical difference between the two code examples, but the first example may involve the creation of a new object that is thrown away.  To not create an unnecessary object, you can use the second example, with `if`/`else`.

Answer (score 2):

Second part would technically be better because it saves some possibly unnecessary object creation and thus helps the Garbage Collector. This is related to what is know as **Lazy Instantiation** which means instantiating objects in memory only if we need them.

Logically, however, both of these are the same.

Here is a good read about [**`Lazy Instantiation`**](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077568/learn-java/java-tip-67--lazy-instantiation.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the variable to an `Object` which gets promptly discarded after execution of if-else statement.The best practice would be to initialize it to `null`,although it is not required but assigning an Object which is never used is pure wastage of heap memory

Comment: But if there's a code path where the variable isn't use, why declare the variable in that scope at all?

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is ever going to be using this code or if you are going to be maintaining this code over a long period of time, it would be better to keep it simple and set it when you create it to some default value.

Comment: "Depends on which language you are in" This question is clearly marked as Java.

Comment: i see the tag now, was looking all over the place, except right were i need to!

Answer (score 0):

I would consider moving the condition inside the `generateSet()` method:

```
Set<T> generateSet() {
    Set<T> theSet = new Set<>();

    if(flagEnabled) {
        // do stuff
    }

    return theSet;
}
```

Then you can simply do

```
mySet = generateSet();
```